how can we use model object method in rails select query
I have two models, first one is User with attributes first_name, last_name and second one is Organization with attribute partner_level which is enum {standard: 'standard',standard_plus: 'standard_plus', premium: 'premium', premium_exclusive: 'premium_exclusive'}.
Now I defined a function in user.rb which tells us specific user charging rate organization
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :organization

  // this is just a simple method for example in real I have a method which have alot of calculation are performing in this method
  def charging_rate
    if organization.standard?
      500
    elsif organization.standard_plus?
      640
    elsif organization.premium?
       870
    elsif organization.premium_exclusive?
      988
    else
      786
    end
  end
end

Now I want to write a query which can take value of charging_rate from user.rb for each object as method using select method, Because this is only example, in real I have calculations in this method.
Something like this way.
User.select("users.*, #{charging_rate} As professional_charging_rate")

I don't know how to achieve this, could anyone help me to achieve this milestone.

You're thinking about this wrong. If area_of_field is a column on the organizations table you would join that table and do User.joins(:organization).select(User.arel_table[Arel.star], Organization.arel_table[:area_of_field].as("professional_working_field")). If area_of_field is a actually a method that needs to be calculated in Ruby you would eager load the organization and just call the method when iterating across the records instead of using select.

You can't actually use a Ruby method in a SQL query.

@max I edited question for your better understanding please have a look now.

Yeah. "If area_of_field is a actually a method that needs to be calculated in Ruby you would eager load the organization and just call the method when iterating across the records instead of using select.". As I said already trying to use a method that exists in your application inside of the database is a fools errand. Totally different environments and sometimes even totally different machines on different continents.

How it would be? could you please write it?

Why not store charging_rate as a field in the database and update it as needed?

@Rana.Amir no - it depends entirely on how your actually using it. Try to understand the concepts instead of expecting to be spoon fed.

actually I am not asking for spoon fed, just wanna see or taking concept how was you thinking, in real code it's already very different calculation. that's why I just added question by created very simple example, to know either is it possible or not or should I need to write the sql query.

@Stefan we have 3 to 4 table which depends on this calculation and base on their column price will be differ day by day so that why we can't add it as a column we have to calculate it runtime.

Can you update your example accordingly to better reflect your actual database structure? Maybe include one or two extra tables to make the problem more obvious. Also include the expected result(s) of the query that you want to run.

@Rana.Amir any reason you can't capture the charging_rate on a daily basis in a table? This would make querying much more possible as well as allow for historical tracking.

I wrote an article on this very same topic a couple of months ago: https://blog.bustikiller.com/2023/10/07/defining-aggregated-attributes-with-activerecord.html
